# Measure Lebesgue-Stieltjes of single point in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\phi(x,y)$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on $R^2$, My question is about the measure of a single point, namely $(a,b)$ in $R^2$.

We know the measure on a rectangular $(a-\frac{1}{m},a] \times (b-\frac{1}{n},b]$, which is $\phi(a,b)+\phi(a-\frac{1}{m},b-\frac{1}{n})-\phi(a-\frac{1}{m},b)-\phi(a,b-\frac{1}{n})$, so we can calculate the measure on a line $\{a\} \times (b-\frac{1}{n},b]$, since $\{a\} \times (b-\frac{1}{n},b]=\cap_{m\in N^+}(a-\frac{1}{m},a] \times (b-\frac{1}{n},b]$, we can have the measure of it is

$$lim_{m\longrightarrow \infty}\phi(a,b)+\phi(a-\frac{1}{m},b-\frac{1}{n})-\phi(a-\frac{1}{m},b)-\phi(a,b-\frac{1}{n})=\phi(a,b)+\phi(a-0,b-\frac{1}{n})-\phi(a-0,b)-\phi(a,b-\frac{1}{n})$$(2)

Now I want to calculate the measure of a single point $(a,b)$. Since $(a,b)=\{a\} \times \cap_{n\in N^+}(b-\frac{1}{n},b]$, we can have it measure by letting $n$ goes to infinity in (2).
So we have $$\phi(a,b)+\phi(a-0,b-0)-\phi(a-0,b)-\phi(a,b-0)$$

> My question is, how can we know $\phi(a-0,b-0)$ exists and does it equal to $\phi(a-0,b)$ since $\phi$ is continuous from right?

I added a picture, which point is $\phi(a-0,b-0)$?
[image]

Comment: Isnt $\phi$ right continuous ? wont right continuity solve ur problem ?

Comment: I know $\phi(a,b-0)$ exists, but I do not know what to do with $\phi(a-0,b-\frac{1}{n})$. To get  $\phi(a-0,b-0)$, we need to approach $(a,b)$ from $\frac{1}{4}$ of the space. (I mean, if we use $y=b$ and $x=a$ divide the space, we need to approach $(a,b)$ from the left downside), $\phi$ is monotone and right continuous W.R.T  x and y, respectively. But I do not know how to deal with something that already is a limit.

Comment: Since $\phi$ is right continuous, by sequential definition of right continuity $\phi(a,b) = \phi(a-0,b) = \phi(a,b-0) = \phi(a-0,b-0)$ since for all these we approach from right side sequentially. So all the four terms cancel each other out resulting in $0$. If $\phi$ is not right continuous, i am not sure though.

Comment: No, $\phi(a-0,b)$ is approaching from the left. They can not cancel each other.

Comment: Oh sorry i meant left continuity. Replace in my comments right with left. If its not left continuous, its a bit of problem and in general u can have some discrete impulse at a point with some weight as measure resulting in failure of left continuity in case of mixed ditributions.

Comment: Regarding existence of $\phi(a-0,b-0)$, isnt $\phi$ increasing in each variable and also w.r.t ordering $(a,b) \leq (a',b')$ iff $a \leq a'$ and $b \leq b'$,  solve ur problem by monotone convergence assuming you r taking limits using both variable jointly and not by taking limits one variable after the other variable?

Comment: Sorry, could you post a detailed answer? I am losing my way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding existence of $\phi(a-0,b-0)$, $\phi(a,b) \geq \phi(a',b')$ for any $a \geq a'$ and $b \geq b'$. So if u set: $a'=a-\frac{1}{n}$ and $b'=b-\frac{1}{n}$ (same $\frac{1}{n}$) then $\phi(a,b) \geq \phi(a-\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}) \geq \phi(a-\frac{1}{n'},b-\frac{1}{n'})$ for any $n' \leq n$. So the sequence $\{\phi(a-\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}): n \geq 1\}$ is a  bounded and monotonic sequence. So the limit exists w.r.t above sequence.
Regarding whether $\phi(a,b)=\phi(a-0,b-0)$, in an arbitrary distribution function for an arbitrary measure, this is not true since we can have mixed distributions with impulse as measures for a paritcular points like $(a,b)$.